# Extract from the second directory

Tags: batch-file

I'm working with the below bat file, and I can't seem to extract the .7z files and skip the first parent folder in the .7z.

For example:
sales2015.7z file has the below directories
sales/engines/parts

sales2010.7z file has the below directories
sales/equipment/parts

When it extracts, I am trying to get it to extract from the second directory. So if the batch worked correctly, the output directory would only have the Engine & Equipment folders and all its subdirectories. If a file with the same name exists, it automatically overwrites.

```
FOR /D /r %%F in ("*") DO (
pushd %CD%
cd %%F
FOR %%X in (*.7z) DO (
    "C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe" x -o "%Z:\master statistics%"
)
popd

)
```

Comment: Try the following parameters : `x %%X "sales/*" -o ...`. I remark that I don't understand your `-o` parameter.

Comment: for the -o I was trying to have it outputted into the Z:\master statistics directory.  Also the sales works if that .7z parent directory is sales, but many of the parent directories are different.  There are about 40-60 different parent directories in the .7z which is why I am trying to omit the first directory

Comment: I also tried the below code, and still kicked out error `System ERROR:
The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\Windows\System32\0409>(
cd C:\Windows\system32\A-Volute
 FOR %X in (.7z) DO ("C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe" x -o"Z:\master statistics\C:\Windows\system32\A-Volute\%~nX" "%X" )
)

C:\Windows\System32\A-Volute>("C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe" x -o"Z:\master statistics\C:\Windows\system32\A-Volute\" ".7z" )

7-Zip 21.07 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2021 Igor Pavlov : 2021-12-26

Scanning the drive for archives:

ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified.
.7z`

Comment: The batch code that procuded the error above was `FOR /D /r %%F in (*) DO (
    cd %%F
    FOR %%X in (.7z) DO (
        "C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe" x -o"Z:\master statistics\%%F\%%~nX" "%%X"
    )
)`